# Making a JButton print a "connecting.." message to a JTextArea whilst attempting to connect to a socket

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm currently working on making a simple chat server program that can handle multiple connected clients at once (to create a basic chatroom) and I've come across a rather minor, but annoying, issue that I can't seem to crack.

I have a JButton that, when clicked, retrieves an IP address, port number and a name that have all been entered by the user in their respective JTextFields. These values are then fed through to the Socket constructor to attempt to open a connection (the name is sent elsewhere and just identifies the user on the server). What I've tried to do is to have a "Connecting..." message displayed in the text area which is then followed by either a successful connection report, or an error (if one is thrown). However, in practice - if I enter a bad IP on purpose (to force an error to be thrown) - no text is appended into the text area until the error is thrown; i.e. it's all appended at once.

Below is the code that is run when the button is clicked:

```
private void submitBtnClicked() {
        String hostName = ipJtf.getText();
        int port = Integer.parseInt(portJtf.getText());
        String name = nameJtf.getText();

        if (!name.trim().equals("")) {

            // This is where I want the code to print "Connecting..."
            jta.setText("");
            jta.append("Connecting...\n");

            try {

                socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
                jta.append("Connected to server on: " + hostName + " : " + port + "\n");

                writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                writer.println(name);

                new ReadThread(socket, this).start();
                new WriteThread(socket, this).start();

            }
            catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                jta.append("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                jta.append("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            jta.setText("");
            jta.append("Please enter a user name before connecting.\n");
        }
    }
```

So when the code is run, it currently would append:

```
Connecting...
I/O Error: Connection refused: connect
```

all at the same time, rather than printing "Connecting..." first and then the error, when it is unsuccessful.

I'm very much a beginner in the scheme of programming, so I'm sure this is just as a result of something basic that I don't understand or just haven't come across in my learning yet, but I really haven't been able to find a solution thus far. I suspect that this is more due to me not being able to figure out what the right question is to ask, as I'm sure someone must have had this issue before and been given a good answer on stackoverflow; if that's the case then I'd very much appreciate being pointed towards it.

Thanks in advance for any and all help on this matter.

P.S: I know the code is a bit messy in its current state - it's mostly due me testing various things as I build the app.

**Additional code for reproduction of issue**

Client.java

```
package ChatServerV2.Client;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.*;

public class Client extends JFrame {

    private JTextField ipJtf = new JTextField(13);
    private JTextField portJtf = new JTextField(4);
    private JTextField nameJtf = new JTextField(15);
    private JTextField messageJtf = new JTextField();
    private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    private Socket socket;

    private String hostName;
    private int port;
    private String userName;

    // IO streams will go here
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client();
    }

    public Client() {
        initUi();



    }

    // Builds the client UI and sets it as visible
    private void initUi() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new JLabel("IP and Port: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        p.add(ipJtf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(portJtf, BorderLayout.EAST);
        // Add jtf listeners

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p2.add(new JLabel("Name: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        p2.add(nameJtf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Add jtf listener

        JPanel p5 = new JPanel();
        p5.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton btn = new JButton("Submit");
        btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            submitBtnClicked();
        });
        p5.add(btn, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p4.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p4.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel p6 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        // p6.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p6.add(p4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p6.add(p5, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p3.add(new JLabel("Message: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        messageJtf.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            sendingAMessage();
        });
        p3.add(messageJtf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Add jtf listener

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(p6, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setTitle("Client");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    /** Writes a message locally to the client's window */
    public void clientWrite(String message) {
        jta.append(message + "\n");
    }

    private void submitBtnClicked() {
        String hostName = ipJtf.getText();
        int port = Integer.parseInt(portJtf.getText());
        String name = nameJtf.getText();

        if (!name.trim().equals("")) {

            jta.setText("");
            jta.append(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() + "\n");
            jta.append("Connecting...\n");
            try {

                socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
                jta.append("Connected to server on: " + hostName + " : " + port + "\n");

                writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                writer.println(name);

                new ReadThread(socket, this).start();
                new WriteThread(socket, this).start();

            }
            catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                jta.append("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                jta.append("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            jta.setText("");
            jta.append("Please enter a user name before connecting.\n");
        }
    }

    private void sendingAMessage() {

    }
}
```

ReadThread.java

```
package ChatServerV2.Client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ReadThread extends Thread {
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private Socket socket;
    private Client client;

    public ReadThread(Socket socket, Client client) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.client = client;

        try {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            client.clientWrite("Error getting input stream: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String response = reader.readLine();
                client.clientWrite(response);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                client.clientWrite("Error reading from server: " + e.getMessage());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WriteThread.java

```
package ChatServerV2.Client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class WriteThread extends Thread {
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private Socket socket;
    private Client client;

    public WriteThread(Socket socket, Client client) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.client = client;

        try {
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            writer = new PrintWriter(output);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            client.clientWrite("Error getting output stream: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void run() {

    }
}
```

As previously mentioned, this is very much a work in progress by a beginner, so if it looks awful, that's because it is.

Comment: I am guessing that you run the long connecting process on the EDT. This should be avoided. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). For more help post [mre] so we do not have to guess.

Comment: @c0der I'll add in all three of the class files necessary to get the Client to work - I only didn't because it felt too cluttered for what is a very specific issue. I understand that it's harder to diagnose without it though, so I'll make that change. I also confirmed that it is running on the EDT by using: javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread().

Comment: Please mind the **M** of MRE. Mre does not mean post-all-code but rather the minimum needed to reproduce the problem.
Also what is the input that reproduces the error ?

Comment: @c0der For example putting in 127.0.0.1 in the IP field, 4444 in the port field and then James in the name field - anything should work really, as long as it fails (i.e. doesn't successfully connect to a socket). To be honest it should have the same problem even if it succeeds, but it's more noticeable when it fails as there's a pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better demonstration of see the problem (and the solution) add a delay to `ReadThread`:

```
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.wait(1); //todo remove after testing 
        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        client.clientWrite("Error getting input stream: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Run `Client` and see that the problem becomes evident.
To fix it you need to take any long process off the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

One simple way to do it is running the long process on a different thread.

The following is `submitBtnClicked` modified to do so:

```
  private void submitBtnClicked() {
        String hostName = ipJtf.getText();
        int port = Integer.parseInt(portJtf.getText());
        String name = nameJtf.getText();

        if (!name.trim().equals("")) {

            jta.setText("");
            jta.append(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() + "\n");
            jta.append("Connecting...\n");
            new Thread(()->{//take long process off the EDT 
                  try {

                      socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
                      //Modifying a Swing component must be done by the EDT 
                      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> jta.append("Connected to server on: " + hostName + " : " + port + "\n"));

                      writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                      writer.println(name);

                      new ReadThread(socket, this).start();
                      new WriteThread(socket, this).start();

                  }
                  catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> jta.append("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage() + "\n"));
                  }
                  catch (IOException e) {
                      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> jta.append("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n"));
                  }
            }).start();
        }
        else {
            jta.setText("");
            jta.append("Please enter a user name before connecting.\n");
        }
    }
```

(Run it online [here](https://repl.it/@c0derrepo/RunClientServerOffTheEDT#Main.java))

Comment: I would use a `SwingWorker`, possibly in combination with a `PropertyChangeListener`.

Comment: @Abra I agree that a `SwingWorker` is the tool for the job. A simple thread is used here for clarity and simplicity. Post a `SwingWorker` based solution, my upvote is guaranteed.

Comment: This did the job brilliantly - thanks for all the effort and help @c0der; my apologies for making it harder than it need to be. I would also be interested to see the `SwingWorker` solution as it seems like the "proper" way to go about it.

Comment: It is. But I think understanding the issue and the solution is easier with a simple thread (which is a legit solution). A `SwingWorker` is a bit more complicated to use.